# Why does this REGEX not match specific literal?

Tags: .net, regex

I have this .NET regex:

```
(<%#)(?<type>((sql)|(magic)|(sqlscalar))):(?<method>([^\s]*)\s*)(\s)*(%>)
```

and it matches `'sqlscalar'` and  `'magic'`  perfectly , but does not match `'sql'`

[image: RegexTester screenshot]

any help appreciated..

here is the server name  <%#sqlscalar:@@servername %> this is result from  funcA with @p valu=100 <%#sqlscalar:dbo.funcA(<%variableA%>)%> : both the functions above is in first line , 
Results of FuncB, and the fMagic() in second line <%#sqlscalar:funcB(<%variableB%>)%> <%#magic:fMagic()%> 
Third line is from sql ‘select * from dbo.ftelUsers()’  <%#sql:select * from dbo.ftElUsers()%>

Comment: Any chance you could post the regex as text instead of an image? (or in addition to)

Comment: I agree with @TimPietzcker, but in addition, your regex needs some cleaning up. What's with all the extraneous parens? Here's your original regex: `(<%#)(?<type>((sql)|(magic)|(sqlscalar))):(?<method>([^\s]*)\s*)(\s)*(%>)`. Here it is, simplified: `<%#(?<type>sql|magic|sqlscalar):(?<method>\S*\s*)%>`

Comment: Here is regex
(<%#)(?<type>((sql)|(magic)|(sqlscalar))):(?<method>([^\s]*)\s*)(\s)*(%>)

Comment: @TonyP: Can you please also provide the test text instead of an image. I don't really feel like typing it myself for testing...

Comment: @Tim, added the text as well , thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't allow whitespace after the colon (unless it's directly before the closing bracket `%>`). That's why `select * from...` doesn't match.

I propose a different regex (*updated* to handle nested tags which I had overlooked before):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"<%[#]         # Match '<%#'
    (?<type>        # Match and capture in group 'type':
     sql            # 'sql'
     (?:scalar)?    # optionally followed by 'scalar'
    |               # OR
     magic          # 'magic'
    )               # End of group 'type'
    :               # Match ':'
    (?<method>      # Match and capture in group 'method'
    (?>             # Either match (possessively):
     (?:            # the following group which matches
      (?!<%|%>)     # only if we're not at the start of <% or %>
      .             # any character
     )+             # once or more
    |               # or
     <% (?<Depth>)  # <% (and increase the nesting counter)
    |               # or
     %> (?<-Depth>) # %> (and decrease the nesting counter).
    )*              # Repeat as needed.
    (?(Depth)(?!))  # Assert that the nesting counter is at zero.
    )               # End of group 'method'
    %>              # Then match a closing %>.
    ", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the right regex to include white spaces before the closing bracket ?

Comment: Thanks Tim, your dissemination of regex is a real eye opener, you are life saver

Comment: This is much better, but it doesn't handle nested tags, which is where I got stuck too. In the example, he has `<%#sqlscalar:funcB(<%variableB%>)%>`, but your regex match will stop at the first `%>`, not the outside one.

Comment: @BrianStephens: Oh, you're right. I didn't see the nested tag - well, the OP *should* have provided text to work with, not an image :) - but this can be fixed. Hold on a sec...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: WOW! I never knew about .NET "balancing groups". That opens up all new regex nesting possibilities! Thank you so much for demonstrating their use.